# Can you create forms to store information with React-Admin?

Tags: javascript, forms, react-admin

I am trying to create a form to get information that will only be stored but not displayed using React-admin. 
So far, I have only seen forms in react-admin when you want to add information to an existing table or if you want to edit information. Is there a way to have the form appear as the first thing and only POST information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when defining your resources under your `<Admin>` component just set the `list` prop to be your Create form.

```
<Resource name="my_resource" list={MyCreateComp} />
```

As long as your resource has a value for list it will show up in the menu.

More info in the [react-admin resource docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Resource.html)